# Display option fields (child) based on parent option condition - JS solutions needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I am looking for a simple .js solution. I have two dropdown buttons - code:

```
<select name="parent_dropdown" id="parent">
    <option value="option_01">parent_option_01</option>
    <option value="option_02">parent_option_02</option>
 </select>
<br />
<select name="child_dropdown" id="child">
    <option value="opt01">child_option_01</option>
    <option value="opt02">child_option_02</option>
    <option value="opt03">child_option_03</option>
    <option value="opt04">child_option_04</option>
 </select>
```

Now I need to accomplish this:

When option_01 in #parent is chosen --->  make available only child_option_01 and child_option_02 in #child dropdown

When option_02 in #parent is chosen --->  make available only child_option_03 and child_option_04 in #child dropdown

I tried some solutions I found online but so far no luck. I have a very basic .js knowledge.

Link to FIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q5kKz/343/

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: First you should have relation between dependent and parent list. then you can make dependent pick-list.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the next step with your fiddle, this will do (almost) what you want:

```
$('#parent').change(function() {
    $("option[value='opt01']")[$(this).val() == "option_01" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
}).change();
```

Notice the attribute selector: `"option[value='opt01']"` - that says "any options with value of opt01".

You should probably expand that selector to be `"#child option[value='opt01']"`

Using a "basic" programming method, you could do this for multiple options:

```
$('#parent').change(function() {
    $("option[value='opt01']")[$(this).val() == "option_01" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
    $("option[value='opt02']")[$(this).val() == "option_01" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
    // Adding multiple options here.  This is a bad method for maintainability
}).change();
```

A better way to go would be to assign some sort of other attributes to the options that should show depending on which parent is selected.  One example is using a class that matches the parent value desired - which would require modifying your child list like so:

```
<select name="child_dropdown" id="child">
    <option value="opt01" class="option_01">child_option_01</option>
    <option value="opt02" class="option_01">child_option_02</option>
    <option value="opt03" class="option_02">child_option_03</option>
    <!-- The below option would show whenever the parent is on option 2 OR 3 -->
    <option value="opt04" class="option_02 option_03">child_option_04</option>
</select>
```

But then your script could be much more usefully constructed like so, and wouldn't need to be changed if you added / changed options:

```
$('#parent').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#child option")[$(this).hasClass(val) ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
}).change();
```

This still leaves the problem of the list option hiding, and the select can still be set to a "hidden" value.  This would need to be addressed somehow.  Something like the below:

```
$('#parent').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#child option")[$(this).hasClass(val) ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
    var child_val = $('#child').val();
    // If the selected option is not visible...
    if ($('#child').find(":selected").not(":visible")) {
        // Set it to the first option that has the proper parent class
        $("#child").val($("#child option." + val + ":first").val());
    };
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of jQuery you could do something like:

```
var group1 = $("#child").find("option[value='opt01'], option[value='opt02']");
var group2 = $("#child").find("option[value='opt03'], option[value='opt04']");

$('#parent').change(function() {
  var selected = $("#parent").find(":selected").text();

  if (selected == "parent_option_01") {
    group1.prop("disabled", false);
    group2.prop("disabled", true);
  } else { 
    group1.prop("disabled", true);
    group2.prop("disabled", false);
}
}).change();
```

Comment: Great! I just replaced disabled to hidden ... cause I don't want options to be shown. It is a possible solution. Now I will chechk others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The other people may have it right. But when you want to make changes you have to change a bunch of JS code. I think this is a better approach. In our child HTML we add a data attribute to show what values of parent will make this child option show. This way if we ever need to add more elements or change what ones make the children appear we can just change the HTML and it leaves our javascript a lot cleaner.

http://jsfiddle.net/q5kKz/348/

```
var parent = $("#parent");
var child = $("#child");
var val;
$('#parent').change(function() {
    //Get value of parent
    val = $("#parent").val();
    //cycle through children and find which data show matches the parent
    child.children().each(function(){ 
        var c = $(this);
        //Jquery's .data wasn't working for some reason
        if(c.attr("data-show") === val){
            c.show()
        }else{
            c.hide()
        }
    })
}).change();
```

In the HTML

```
<select name="parent_dropdown" id="parent">
    <option value="option_01">parent_option_01</option>
    <option value="option_02">parent_option_02</option>
</select>
<br />
<select name="child_dropdown" id="child">
    <option value="opt01" data-show="option_01">child_option_01</option>
    <option value="opt02" data-show="option_01">child_option_02</option>
    <option value="opt03" data-show="option_02">child_option_03</option>
    <option value="opt04" data-show="option_02">child_option_04</option>
</select>
```